# heatmap with multiple RowSideColors

Tags: r, heatmap

I am  creating a heatmap for a given matrix. I also separately have multiple factors  to be shown along with the heatmap. Right now I could create one RowSideColors for one factor. But is there a way to create RowSideColors for multiple factors from gplots heatmap.2 function?
In other words, many RowSideColors with the heatmap. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted, I've attempted to include a reproducible example below in case anyone else has a similar question:

```
require(gplots)
data(mtcars)
df  <- as.matrix(mtcars[,8:11])
df = df[order(rownames(df)),]  # sorts the rows in alphabetical order
# specifying a column dendrogram
heatmap.2(df, Rowv=FALSE, dendrogram=c("column"))
```

The resulting heatmap is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After bit of digging, I found the solution myself that if you specify

```
  tmpSorted = tmp[order(rownames(tmp)),]  # sorts alphabetical order
  heatmap.2(tmpSorted, Rowv=F .... )
```

the option Rowv=F  works!